# Is there a built-in python method that iterates over a list using index values instead of elements

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a python method that iterates over a list using index values instead of the actual elements itself. The code does exactly this:

```
for index in range(len(list)-1):
    # do stuff
```

I am looking to see if there is already a function that does this or if I should add it myself.

Comment: The syntax is deliberately awkward, to discourage you from doing this. `enumerate` is somewhat better. (Any particular reason you're skipping the last element?)

Comment: @user2357112 just curious, why is enumerate the better choice?

Comment: @Racialz: One less set of parentheses, and usually, if you want the indices, you still also want the values. `enumerate` gives you both.

Comment: I admit that I still use `for i in range(len(list)): `, it's hard to throw that paradigm overboard if you have programmed in lower level languagues for a long time. I also don't like to overload new pythonistas that have previous programming skills right at the start. You can learn basic Python, coming from C, Fortran, Pascal, Java etc. in one afternoon as they say, but good practices take a little longer. Good question, good comments, good answer.

Comment: The `for ... range` is common in `numpy` code that *must* iterate.  The `enumerate` approach only lets you iterate on the 1st axis.   And if using the index you probably have to index several arrays, for both read and write.

Answer (score 7):

Use `enumerate`:

```
for index, ignore_this_its_the_value in enumerate(list):
   # do stuff
```

But actually:

```
for index in range(len(list)):
   # do stuff
```

does produce the proper indexes.

Comment: It’s idiomatic to use a single underscore for an unused variable: `for i, _ in enumerate(...)`

Answer (score 1):

`for i in x:` works on any iterable, such as a list or generator.

`range(r)` or `xrange(r)` is just a list of numbers (or generator of such a list).  `enumerate` is a convenient of generating both counters and values from a list.  You could do the same thing with a `zip(range(len(alist)), alist)`.

```
for i, value in enumerate(alist):
    alist[i] = foo(value)
```

is, I think, a good example of using enumerate.  It provides both an efficient way of 'reading' the values, and a way of modifying them.

Of course if you need more control over the iteration there is always the `while` loop.  It's particularly useful if you need to continue or break, or if you need to change the index in unusual ways.

Generators are another good tool for packaging an iteration.

Personally I like the list comprehension (and the generator and dictionary analogs) best.  It's a good blend of control and compactness.